# Are there terms for homophones that vary by syllabic emphasis?

Tags: terminology, stress, homonymy

Is there a technical term for words that have the same phonemes but are distinguished by syllabic emphasis?

E.g., *abstract* is æb-strækt, but emphasis on the first syllable is a different word from emphasis on the same syllable.  Other examples: *permit*, *convict*.  (Offhand it seems I can only think of words that are related in meaning, but I suspect there are examples of unrelated words.  ETA: Found one: *present*.)

(I see that *heteronym* refers to words with the same spelling, but those can have different pronunciations, and I'm asking about the spoken word, without regard to spelling.)

Comment: Many two-syllable nouns in English have homophones that are verbs and are stressed differently. Some American English dialects (the so-called "POlice UMbrella" lects) have a tendency to stress two-syllable nouns on the first syllable, like CIGarette or INsurance, whether they are deverbal or not.

Comment: _Present_ the verb and _present_ the noun are related too, though perhaps not as closely, semantically, as many other such pairs.

Comment: In relation to your addition about _heteronyms_, words like these are usually **homographs**, that is, words that are spelt the same but pronounced differently. It’s a highly productive process in English to form noun/verb pairs in this way, and the resulting pair are virtually always spelt the same. Homographness is not, however, based on stress – it can be any difference in pronunciation, like different number of syllables (_[for someone’s] sake_ vs _[Japanese] sake_) or different vowel qualities (_[the] wind_ vs _wind [a clock]_).

Answer (score 3):

These words are a subset of *minimal pairs*. A minimal pair is a pair of words (perceived by speakers as different) distinguished solely by some salient feature (in this case stress location).

I would describe these words as *English minimal pairs for stress location*. It's not a snappy name, but it is an accurate description of what they are.

Answer (score 0):

The best term to name those words is [homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone). The reason for this term to be suitable for what you are looking for is that it is made up of *homo-* “same” and *phone* “sound”, there is nothing related to writing in the name. And secondly, and more important, it is the term *homophones* that is [used in Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone#Mandarin_Chinese) to refer to words having the same phonemes, but different phonemic tones which are analogous to what you call ‘syllabic emphasis’ — a suprasegmental feature distinguishing otherwise identical strings of phonemes: *mā* (妈) "mother", *má* (麻) "hemp", mă (马) "horse", mà (骂) "scold", and ma (吗) “yes/no question particle” constitute a set of *homophones*. Polysyllabic homophones are also [numerous in Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5921/resources-listing-polysyllabic-mandarin-words-with-same-pronunciation-differing) since the number of possible phonemic syllable shells in Mandarin is just a bit more than 400.

Comment: Syllables with the same phonemes but different tones are _not_ usually called homophones in Mandarin in my experience. The Wikipedia article perhaps does this once with the term ‘homophonic syllables’ (though _syllable_ does not necessarily include tone), but the other instances refer to actual homophones, including tone, which is the only way I’ve seen it used, and also [how it’s usually defined in Chinese](https://baike.baidu.com/item/同音字). Similarly, I would never call /ˈrekərd/ and /rɨˈkɔrd/ homophones in English since they’re made up of incompatible phonemes.

Comment: words differing by stress position are emphatically _not_ homophonous. I also agree with @JanusBahsJacquet that I've usually not heard Chinese words differing only in tone called homophonous by people with a linguistic education (although they often are by laypeople). One could potentially describe words that differ solely by tone or stress location as homophones _sensu lato_, but even then it seems stretching the definition more than is reasonable, even with the qualification that we're speaking in a broad sense